# Unable to read file in php

Tags: php

I am trying to get the file path from user and then try to parse it. However, i get error when i run the code.

If i pass the file path manually by putting in my code and then run the program it works fine.

```
<?php

require_once('SoftLayer/SoapClient.class.php'); 
$handle4 = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
echo "Enter full file path of the csv file e.g C:\\git\\softlayer-api-php-client\\sample.csv : ";
$path = fgets($handle4);
echo $path;


$f_pointer=fopen(trim($path),"r"); // file pointer

echo 'Done';

?>
```

Error:
[image]

```
Line 10 $f_pointer=fopen($path,"r");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting the error in your screenshot to text:

```
Warning: fopen(C:\\git\\softlayer-api-php-client\\sample.csv"
)
```

That's not word-wrap of the output, because there are longer lines shown, so that must be an actual newline. There's also a stray double-quote there.

In other words, you need to a) validate your input (so that you'd spot the stray `"` you entered when testing), and b) run [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim) over it before use, to get rid of the almost inevitable spaces and newlines resulting from its entry.

Comment: my bad i did try without the " but i get PHP Warning:  feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given ? I also trimmed the String

Comment: Use `trim($path)`, not `$path.trim()`. "." is the string concatenation operator in PHP.